# jQuery event wait until the data gets loaded in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I am loading my partial views in a page using `$("div").load(url)` event. So that Page will render faster. But with this `$(document).ready` is getting fired even before the content gets loaded. 
I have tried `$(window).load` also, but this is also getting fired even before the content loading.

Can you please suggest a way to wait until the data gets loaded then only execute my javascript functions.

Comment: What is the issue here? `$(document).ready` *has* to fire before you call `load()` - otherwise the `div` element you update will not be accessible.

Comment: My issue is that I have to fire a method after entire page data gets loaded. I am hiding few controls in document.ready of child JS since document.ready is getting fired before my data gets loaded, It is unable to find those controls in DOM. Please suggest a solution. Finally I want to hide few controls based on the data I get from service.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use delegated events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using $("div").load(url), You are loading the url content asynchronously.
Which means that document.load is first initialised and then async call is made to load(url).

Put all your initialization Javascript in a Function (lets say myinit() ) and fire it on success call back of your load method
Eg

```
// this line keeps all your function in one global name space and you can extend it multiple times in same document or js files
var myapp = myapp||{}; 
$(function(){
    // Here you are extending your myapp object with custom init function
    myapp.init = function(){
        //your init code here
    }

    //your ajax content load here
    $('div').load(url,function(){
        //Here you call it
        myapp.init();
    })
})
```

P.S. you can always test your custom methods in console using myapp.init() anywhere in jQuery exec block

Comment: Good idea, but my load method is in loop and in Parent JS from where I cannot access "myapp" variable which is in child JS files.

Comment: Then just define myapp right after jquery.js and then followed by your code.

Comment: mark the answer as correct so its useful for people stuck with same  problem :)